# Mudar de background VIDEO por tamanho de Tela?

Tags: css, html5, typescript, scss

Como utilizar background video diferentes por tamanho de tela ,
Desktop seria um `<video>` 
Mobile seria outro `<video>`

Projeto em Angular ..

```html
<video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" loop">
      <source src="../assets/HomeBack.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
    </video>
```

```html
<video playsinline="playsinlineMobile" autoplay="autoplay" loop">
      <source src="../assets/HomeBackMobile.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
    </video>
```

Answer (score 2):

Cara vc pode ter um simples `@media` para mostrar um e esconder o outro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.mobile {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {

    .mobile {
        display: block;
    }

    .desktop {
        display: none;
    }

}
```

```html
<video class="desktop" width="400" nocontrols autoplay muted>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<video class="mobile" width="400" nocontrols autoplay muted>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score -2):

Você pode esta utilizando o media queries do css.
Exemplo:

```
.teste {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
   .teste {
     margin-left: -211px;
   }
}
```